# why findviewbyposition( ) of recyclerView returns null only sometimes

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

this is my code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_aircraft, container, false);

    recyclerView=(RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerAircraftAdd);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    adapter = new AircraftAdapter(getActivity(),path);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    Button button = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.salvaereo);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
          adapter = (AircraftAdapter)recyclerView.getAdapter();
          ParseObject aircraft = new ParseObject("Aircrafts");

           for(int i = 0;i<adapter.getItemCount(); i++)
           {
             if (i== 0)  //first card
             {
                View view = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(i);
                ImageView image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.aircfraftImg);
                image.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                image.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bm = image.getDrawingCache();
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();
                ParseFile file = new ParseFile("Image.jpg",bytes);
                aircraft.put("aircraft_image",file);

                 file.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                     @Override
                     public void done(ParseException e) {
                         Log.d("sa","tutto ok");
                     }
                 });

             }
             else if (i ==1) //second card
             {
                 View view = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(i);
                 EditText immatricolazione =(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.immatricolazione);
                 EditText modello = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.modello);
                 EditText manifacturer = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.manifacturer);
                 EditText categoria = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.categoria);
                 EditText classe = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.classe);
                 EditText velocita = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.velocita);
                 EditText autonomia = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.autonomia);
                 EditText consumo = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.consumo);
                 EditText posti = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.postitotali);
                 EditText costo = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.costorario);

                 aircraft.put("re",immatricolazione.getEditableText().toString());
                 aircraft.put("ml",modello.getEditableText().toString());
                 aircraft.put("man",manifacturer.getEditableText().toString());
                 aircraft.put("Aircraft_Type",categoria.getEditableText().toString());
                 aircraft.put("ar",classe.getEditableText().toString());
                 aircraft.put("post",Integer.parseInt(posti.getEditableText().toString()));
                 aircraft.put("meter",Integer.parseInt(consumo.getEditableText().toString()));
                 aircraft.put("speed",Integer.parseInt(velocita.getEditableText().toString()));
                 aircraft.put("prezzi",Float.parseFloat(costo.getEditableText().toString()));
                 aircraft.put("fuel",Integer.parseInt(autonomia.getEditableText().toString()));
             }
             else if(i==2) //third card
             {
                 View view = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(i);
                 EditText description = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.description);
                 aircraft.put("descrizione", description.getEditableText().toString());

                 aircraft.put("User", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());

                 dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", "Caricamento aereo in corso...", true);

                 aircraft.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

                     public void done(ParseException e) {
                         dialog.dismiss();

                         if (e == null) {
                             new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                                     .setMessage("Caricamento aereo avvenuto con successo!")
                                     .setCancelable(false)
                                     .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                         @Override
                                         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                         }
                                     }).create().show();
                         } else {
                             new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                                     .setMessage("Non è stato possibile caricare l'aereo, riprova più tardi!")
                                     .setCancelable(false)
                                     .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                         @Override
                                         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                         }
                                     }).create().show();
                         }


                     }
                 });
             }
           }

        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

but there is this problem: if I charge a photo (first card) and press button, it uploads the photo, but if I write into EditText, it crashes and gives me this error:

> Process: com.run.flyproject, PID: 10796
>                                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                      at com.run.flyproject.Fragments.AddAircraftFragment$1.onClick(AddAircraftFragment.java:78)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

Comment: The amount of Views and the amount of Items are different. RecyclerView only creates as many views it needs to fill its size. A returned null means the View doesn't exist for that item position.

Comment: but i have only 3 views..

Comment: "null if the position is not laid out".  Either way the View doesn't exist and you have to prepare for it.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html#findViewByPosition(int)

Comment: so how could I fix it?

Comment: Declare your rootView final and use `rootView.findViewById(...);` in your onClickListener. This is still hacky, you need to be using ViewHolders.

Comment: what do you mean about "hacky"?@zgc7009 I also want to use viewHolder but I don't know how to do them (button is in the fragment, non in the items of recyclerview)

Comment: I misread your question, I thought this was the adapters method, this is in a fragment? If the view isn't ready in the RecyclerAdapter you can't use it yet.  You are going to have to do some work to get this to do what you want. Maybe set a boolean in your adapter on button click that says you want to save the images loaded into the adapter's image views if they aren't already saved. You will need some way to tell the newly created views whether or not you want their ImageView's source saved to a file.

Comment: is there a way to return result from adapter?

Comment: The problem is the adapter wants to be dynamic, it doesn't want to hold onto _all_ of the data it loads, it just wants to hold onto what is relevant based on the current scroll position. You would either need to hold all of the images that get loaded (bad) or figure out a way to let the adapter know that it needs to save the images that are loaded without duplicating saves (trickier). You could create a SparseArray of booleans that has a boolean associated with each position letting you know whether or not the image in that position has been saved, but that assumes the adapter never changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that this is an explicit answer (the explicit answer would be something like "Your adapter count doesn't coincide with the views available from your adapter"), but my comments were probably getting a bit confusing. You could do something like this...

```
public class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourViewHolder>{

    private boolean mSaveImages = false;
    private SparseArray<Boolean> mImageSavedFlags = new SparseArray<>();

    public void toggleSaveStatus(){
        mSaveImages = !mSaveImages;
    }

    // ... your code

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(YourViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        // Could also manage this in a loop or something
        // in your constructor/when you set your adapter data
        // but this will set our SparseArray
        if(mImageSavedFlags.get(position) == null)
            mImageSavedFlags.put(position, false);

        // ... your code
        if(mSaveImages && !mImageSavedFlags.get(position){
            // ... save your image
            mImageSavedFlags.put(position, true);
        }
    }

    // ... your code
}
```

This way whenever you attempt to bind a view, you can check if you want to save the ImageViews source and if you haven't already saved it, if you haven't it will save the source and update the SparseArray.

To toggle your status just do something like this

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        adapter.toggleSaveStatus();
    }
}
```

It is worth noting that this will only save images that you actually scroll to *after* you toggle the save setting on. I suppose you could force scrolling of you RecyclerView but that is getting into something else.

It is also important to realize that if you are doing something like loading images from a URL or from your drawables based on position or something, you don't actually need your ImageView to load the source before you can save it, there are plenty of ways (including libraries) to save images that haven't been explicitly loaded into your app yet, which would completely remove the need to include your adapter in the process.

**I am sure this isn't the only way to do this, and I am sure this isn't the best answer, but again my comments were getting a bit confusing.**

Answer (score 1):

You can use use both

recyclerViewInstance.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(adapterPosition)  and
recyclerViewInstance.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(layoutPosition).
Be sure that RecyclerView view uses two type of positions

Adapter position : Position of an item in the adapter. This is the position from the Adapter's perspective.
Layout position : Position of an item in the latest layout calculation. This is the position from the LayoutManager's perspective.
You should use getAdapterPosition() for findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(adpterPosition) and getLayoutPosition() for findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(layoutPosition).

Take a member variable to hold previously selected item position in recyclerview adapter and other member variable to check whether user is clicking for first time or not.

Sample code and screen shots are attached for more information at the bottom.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {     

private RecyclerView mRecyclerList = null;    
private RecyclerAdapter adapter = null;    

@Override    
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);    

    mRecyclerList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerList);    
}    

@Override    
protected void onStart() {    
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = null;    
    String[] daysArray = new String[15];    
    String[] datesArray = new String[15];    

    super.onStart();    
    for (int i = 0; i < daysArray.length; i++){    
        daysArray[i] = "Sunday";    
        datesArray[i] = "12 Feb 2017";    
    }    

    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(mRecyclerList, daysArray, datesArray);    
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);    
    mRecyclerList.setAdapter(adapter);    
    mRecyclerList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);    
}    
}    


public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyCardViewHolder>{          

private final String TAG = "RecyclerAdapter";        
private Context mContext = null;        
private TextView mDaysTxt = null, mDateTxt = null;    
private LinearLayout mDateContainerLayout = null;    
private String[] daysArray = null, datesArray = null;    
private RecyclerView mRecyclerList = null;    
private int previousPosition = 0;    
private boolean flagFirstItemSelected = false;    

public RecyclerAdapter(RecyclerView mRecyclerList, String[] daysArray, String[] datesArray){    
    this.mRecyclerList = mRecyclerList;    
    this.daysArray = daysArray;    
    this.datesArray = datesArray;    
}    

@Override    
public MyCardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {    
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = null;    
    View view = null;    
    MyCardViewHolder cardViewHolder = null;    
    mContext = parent.getContext();    
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);    
    view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.date_card_row, parent, false);    
    cardViewHolder = new MyCardViewHolder(view);    
    return cardViewHolder;    
}    

@Override    
public void onBindViewHolder(MyCardViewHolder holder, final int position) {    
    mDaysTxt = holder.mDaysTxt;    
    mDateTxt = holder.mDateTxt;    
    mDateContainerLayout = holder.mDateContainerLayout;    

    mDaysTxt.setText(daysArray[position]);    
    mDateTxt.setText(datesArray[position]);    

    if (!flagFirstItemSelected){    
        mDateContainerLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);    
        flagFirstItemSelected = true;    
    }else {    
        mDateContainerLayout.setBackground(null);    
    }    
}    

@Override    
public int getItemCount() {    
    return daysArray.length;    
}    

class MyCardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{    
    TextView mDaysTxt = null, mDateTxt = null;    
    LinearLayout mDateContainerLayout = null;    
    LinearLayout linearLayout = null;    
    View view = null;    
    MyCardViewHolder myCardViewHolder = null;    

    public MyCardViewHolder(View itemView) {    
        super(itemView);    
        mDaysTxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.daysTxt);    
        mDateTxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateTxt);    
        mDateContainerLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateContainerLayout);    

        mDateContainerLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    
            @Override    
            public void onClick(View v) {    
                LinearLayout linearLayout = null;    
                View view = null;    

                if (getAdapterPosition() == previousPosition){    
                    view = mRecyclerList.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(previousPosition).itemView;    
                    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.dateContainerLayout);    
                    linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);    
                    previousPosition = getAdapterPosition();    

                }else {    
                    view = mRecyclerList.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(previousPosition).itemView;    
                    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.dateContainerLayout);    
                    linearLayout.setBackground(null);    

                    view = mRecyclerList.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(getAdapterPosition()).itemView;    
                    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.dateContainerLayout);    
                    linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);    
                    previousPosition = getAdapterPosition();    
                }    
            }    
        });    
    }    
}
```

} 
1
source

[image: screen shot 1][image: scrren shot 2]

Answer (score 0):

you are getting `NullPointerException` as your `recyclerView.getLayoutManager().find...` returns `null` and your second question why you don't get view by position, check `recyclerView.getLayoutManager().getChildCount()` to verify that you have any child for that index